# CSS cleaner for firefox 10.0.X

Tags: css

I am looking for a `CSS cleaner` which works with firefox 10.0.x like [`Dust-Me Selectors`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/).

Unfortunately at the moment, `Dust-Me Selectors` is not available for Firefox 10.0.x.

Any idea how to run a tool for find unused CSS selectors, preferably an online tool?

Comment: Duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/how-can-i-find-unused-unapplied-css-rules-in-a-stylesheet

Comment: In the dupe you will find more tools in the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://unused-css.com/

It has a free to use version but with usage limitations.

http://unused-css.com/pricing